# Windows Authentication en NetCore - Formulario

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Saludos estoy creando una nueva aplicacion en la organizacion,  es para usarla en la intranet y quiero aplicar windows authentication por defecto cuando configuramos el proyecto con windows authentication authentica el usuario que se logeo en el pc y no pide credenciales al usuario la pregunta es, hay alguna forma de poner un formulario que authentique el usuario al momento de acceder a la aplicacion ?  y Que no sea de manera automatica al usuario iniciar seccion en la maquina ?

Comment: Si usas seguridad de windows esta se integra con el sistema operativo, no hay formulario que puedas agregar. Pero si podrias ver de aceder con otro browser distinto a IE, estos deberina mostrarte un dislogo donde ingresar las credenciales de dominio, sino tambien desde una ventana de incognito del browser

Comment: Entiendo  en caso de que quiera crear un login para validar los usuarios de active directory y asi poder dar el acceso es posible ?

Answer (score 0):

Si nacesitas un login que aunentique contra un dominio de windows, no integras el sitio web, sino que redefines la seguridad de asp.net membership

Usarisa las clase

[ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider?view=netframework-4.5)

definiendo el cnnection string a `LDAP`

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="LDAP://test.mydomain.com/CN=Users,DC=test,DC=mydomain,DC=com" name="ADConnectionString" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Entonces si podrias programar un login que usar esa clases para utenticar contra el dominio de windows

[Using Forms Authentication with Membership Providers in ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspalliance.com/1658_Using_Forms_Authentication_with_Membership_Providers_in_ASPNET_20.2)

[Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923105425/http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/05/18/forms-authentication-with-active-directory-in-asp.net-2.0.aspx)

En este caso configuras el provider

```
<membership defaultProvider="DomainLoginMembershipProvider">

   <providers>

     <add name="DomainLoginMembershipProvider" 

          type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 

          connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 

          connectionUsername="dotnetinspiration.com\administrator" connectionPassword="youradminpassword"/>

   </providers>

 </membership>
```